# Troubleshooting 'Cannot read property , undefined' errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, octokit-js

I have this function

```js
  function getAvailableProviders(tmpDir, snips, processRepo) {
  const octokit = require("@octokit/rest");
  octokit.repos.listForOrg(
    { org: "terraform-providers", type: "public", per_page: 100 },
    (error, result) => {
      result.data.forEach((element) => {
        processRepo(tmpDir, element.name, snips, iterateOnDocFiles);
      });
    },
  );
}
```

When I run my program, I get this error from the typescript compiler

```
(node:15713) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'listForOrg' of undefined
```

The problem is according to the octokit documentation, the `repos.listForOrg` is defined.

https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-list-for-org

I'm just trying to learn (typescript and node), while at the same time recreate something that has been abandoned by the original devleoper.  I have my require statement, according to the octokit documentation. it's not reaching out to the api.  Is there something else I need to have installed in my node project to make this work correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at the usage documentation: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#usage? It looks like you need to destructure `Octokit`: `const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");`. And then set it up with the proper configuration and the return value of that is what exposes `repos.listForOrg`.

Comment: isn't that what I'm doing with line 2 ??

Comment: for what it's worth, I rewrote that line same as in the docs, and listed above, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a slight change to your `require` and add `const octokit = new Octokit();` after the require (insert as line 3 in your example):

```
  function getAvailableProviders(tmpDir, snips, processRepo) {
  const { Octokit } = require('@octokit/rest'); // <-- change this line
  const octokit = new Octokit(); // <-- add this line
  octokit.repos.listForOrg(
    { org: "terraform-providers", type: "public", per_page: 100 },
    (error, result) => {
      result.data.forEach((element) => {
        processRepo(tmpDir, element.name, snips, iterateOnDocFiles);
      });
    },
  );
}
```

see [octokit readme](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js#readme)